# JavaScript Function Parameter is returning as Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I was browsing all questions around before posting here. It's better to show than explain since it's so simple.

I have the **JS** code simplified so you can test the problem:

```
    var output = "";
var num = 0;

var rotor1 = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","X","Y","Z"];
var rotor2 = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","X","Y","Z"];
var rotor3 = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","W","X","Y","Z"];

var rotor1Position = 5;
var rotor2Position = 12;
var rotor3Position = 4;

function Encript(input)
{
    result = "";
    for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        result += DoEncript(input.charAt(i));   
    }
    num = 0;
    return result;
}

function Decript(input)
{
    result = "";
    for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        result += DoDecript(input.charAt(i));
    }
    num = 0;
    return result;
}

function Encript(input)
{
    output = "ENCRYPT: " + input + "<br>";
    if((rotor1.indexOf(input) + rotor1Position) > rotor1.length - 1)
    {
        num = rotor1.indexOf(input) + rotor1Position - rotor1.length;
    }
    else
    {
        num = rotor1.indexOf(input) + rotor1Position;
    }
    output += "rotor1 = " + rotor1[num] + "<br>";
    if((num + rotor2Position) > rotor2.length - 1)
    {
        num = num + rotor2Position - rotor2.length;
    }
    else
    {
        num += rotor2Position;
    }   
    output += "rotor2 = " + rotor2[num] + "<br>";
    if((num + rotor3Position) > rotor3.length - 1)
    {
        num = num + rotor3Position - rotor3.length;
    }
    else
    {
        num += rotor3Position;
    }   
    output += "rotor3 = " + rotor3[num] + "<br>";
    result = output + "<hr>";
}

function Decript(input)
{
    output = "DECRYPT: " + input + "<br>";
    if((rotor1.indexOf(input) - rotor1Position) < 0)
    {
        num = rotor1.length - ((num - rotor1Position)*-1);
    }
    else
    {
        num = rotor1.indexOf(input) - rotor1Position;
    }
    output += "rotor1 = " + rotor1[num] + "<br>";
    if((num - rotor2Position) < 0)
    {
        num = rotor2.length - ((num - rotor2Position)*-1);
    }
    else
    {
        num -= rotor2Position;
    }
    output += "rotor2 = " + rotor2[num] + "<br>";
    if((num - rotor3Position) < 0)
    {
        num = rotor3.length - ((num - rotor3Position)*-1);
    }
    else
    {
        num -= rotor3Position;
    }
    output += "rotor3 = " + rotor3[num] + "<br>";
    result = output;
}
```

The **HTML** call is simple:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Encription</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="enigma3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Encript('Y');">
        <div id="result">ENIGMA</div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

It returns as *undefined*. It's like if I wasn't passing any parameter. I really can't understand why.

Thank you for saving me from this ridiculous issue,

Comment: Okay...I'll insert all the code I can get. Thanks...just a sec.

Comment: What's `result`? What's `DoEncript`? What's `num` and why is it there?

Comment: try declaring `result` outside the loop

Comment: You need to initialize `result` at the beginning of the function.

Comment: Hi guys,

I did what you told:
```
function Encript(input)
{
    result = "";
    for(i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        result += DoEncript(input.charAt(i));   
    }
    num = 0;
    return result;
}```

Still having the same problem.

Comment: The code you posted works as expected if the JS is in the same file.

Comment: What steps have you taken to fix the issue? Maybe just start putting `return output` in `Encript` to start narrowing it down. **Noting that currently you do not return anything from `Encript` at all.** (The long one; you seem to have two.)

Comment: Please revert the edit; this code will not exhibit the described issue and just adds confusion :)

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton. I have no idea how to revert the edit. Is it just copy and paste the code or something? It still need some improvements.

Comment: Click on the `edited 15 mins ago` (or whatever) link and click a reasonable "revert" link. Questions should not be continually edited if those edits *change the meaning and context of the question*, otherwise the answers and comments refer to code or prose no longer present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript variables that aren't declared don't have an automatic value. Instead, they remain as `undefined`. Therefore, you must declare it before you return it like so:

```js
function Encript(input) {
  let result = "";
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    result += DoEncript(input.charAt(i));
  }
  num = 0;
  return result;
}
function DoEncript(char){
  //Your actual code here
  return "a";
}
```

```html
<body onload="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Encript('YFG');">
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Adding that `result` should really be declared with a `let` to avoid leaking into the global namespace.

Comment: @DaveNewton Good call

Comment: Hi Spectric! Thanks. 

I'm declaring the result as a global variable, before the function starts.

Comment: @Methark OK. Could you show us your full JS code then?

Comment: Declared as you said @Spectric. Still returning as undefined.

Comment: The last two functions names are DoEncript and DoDecript. Copy and paste mistake.

Comment: @Methark You return nothing from either.

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton! I Should be returning the "result" since it was a global variable. I've changed because @Spectric code example. The actual problem seems to not be reading the function parameter.

Comment: @Methark You are setting a value to the result of calling `DoEncript` when you write `result += DoEncript(input.charAt(i))`. If the function being called doesn't return anything, which it doesn't, there will be an implicit return of `undefined`. The word `return` means something. Please don't start down the road of shoveling data into global variables: be explicit, or at least *consistent*.

Comment: @DaveNewton - Why DoEncript(input.charAt(i)) returns nothing?

Comment: @Methark You tell me; I didn't write it. The *technical* reason is because there's no `return` statement. That's what `return` does: returns a value.

Comment: @DaveNewton and @Spectric!!! I GOT IT!!! It was soooo simple!!! Thanks for helping me to look deep into the code!!!